# Odd BCNF Decomposition on my past exam

Tags: database-normalization, bcnf

I have a problem breaking this into BCNF:

```
Relation: R[A E P M N S T L]

FD's:
A -> EM, 
A -> L, 
M -> ST,
M -> N,
S -> T, 
E -> P, 
P -> E, 
L -> A
```

This one was on one of my past exams, and I don't really know how to solve it.

I learned this on coursera by the woman (Jennifer Widom) who wrote our course literature:

```
-------------- BCNF ALGORITHM ------------
1. Take a FD that violates BCNF.
2. Decompose the FD to two other relations
3. First relation: The whole FD
4. Second relation: The rest of the Relation + the left hand side of the chosen FD 
5. Iterate until all the new relations have key on its left hand side
-------------- BCNF ALGORITHM ------------

And I also tried another one that is basically the same, but written in a different way:
X->Y: R1({X}+), R2(R - {X}+ ; X) (Relation minus {X}+ (XY in this case), plus X.
```

So far, I'm here:
Obviously, A is key, so its FDs are already in BCNF. Question is, can I erase any redundant FDs maybe? If so, what is the thumb rule?

```
R1(MST) <-- BCNF.
R2(A E P M N L)
R3()
```

And have no idea where to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Take a FD that violates BCNF.
5. Iterate until all the new relations have key on its left hand side
```

Step 1 in mentioning BCNF violation can only make sense if it means you should identify the keys and non-key-implied FDs of each original and generated relation. Also, step 5 termination cannot be merely when there is a key on the left hand side, because a non-key determiner could be present. Clearly it is necessary and sufficient to stop when all relations are in BCNF. A particular full description of an algorithm may describe equivalent reorganizations and/or tests without explicitly mentioning BCNF.

If A is a key then so is L since L->A.

```
MSTNAELP keys A and L plus M->ST, S->T, E<->P
```

Those FDs are from non-keys. You picked M->ST. We get:

```
MST key M plus S->T
MNAELP keys A and L plus E<->P
```

Both have determiners not from keys, hence are not in BCNF. Pick S->T and E->P. We get:

```
ST key S in BCNF
SM key M in BCNF
EP keys P and E in BCNF
EMNAL keys A and L in BCNF
```